# Downgrading from java se 8 to java se 7?

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I built a web application in `JAVA SE 8` using tomcat 8 but my hosting provider uses `java se 7` and tomcat 7 on their web server. That's why I am getting error while deploying it. Please tell what i should do? Do i have to uninstall java se 8 and install its 7th version?

Comment: Is the server linux or windows? Do you want to change your desktop version of Java or the servers?

Comment: how did you build the application? in Eclipse or another IDE? if so, you shoudl reconfigure the IDE to use the 7 JDK (installing it if necessary) , and use it to rebuild your distribution package.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 i build this web app using netbeans and my application runs fine when i deploy it locally.

Comment: Here is information on how to configure which SDK NetBeans uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on Note however that since Netbeans is often packaged with an SDK download, that you might as well just switch to using the NetBeans instance packaged with SDK 7. Multiple Netbeans instances can be run on a system. you may have to finagle tomcat however.